# DigitalOcean + Google Domains DNS not working

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a domain name with Google Domains and a VPS with DigitalOcean.  I was reading [how to setup a hostname](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean) on DigitalOcean and following instructions there.

I have a domain set up as such on DigitalOcean

[image]

Where the @ line has the value of my droplet's IP address (that is correct).

On Google Domains I have DNS setup like so

[image]

so, according to the instruction

> You can also connect your IP to a domain name with nothing before it (this should also occur by default when you add a domain):...To accomplish this, create a new hostname with the symbol "@' in the hostname field.

So according to this, I should be able to type my domain name in the browser and the site on my IP address should be there.  I know the site is working because when I go to the IP address itself, the site is there, but when I use the domain name, I get the error:

```
 server DNS address could not be found.
```

I have followed the instructions, and I have no idea why it can't find the DNS address.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will take time to reflect. When you have added ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because server configuration and DNS are best suited on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there any way I can move it over to serverfault.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today Digital Ocean has problems with the DNS:
https://status.digitalocean.com/

Answer (score 1):

looks like DO is having a problem this morning with DNS which would cause this 
[image: issue]